# HotChocolate UsePaging or UseOffsetPaging slows down the query to more than 30 seconds

Tags: c#, graphql, entity-framework-core, hotchocolate

I'm new to HotChocolate and graphql but this issue that I have at the moment with HotChocolate is a bit strange.

So I'm using the following packages in a dotnet 6.0 webapi project:

1. HotChocolate.AspNetCore @ 12.5.0
2. HotChocolate.AspNetCore.Authorization @ 12.5.0
3. HotChocolate.Data @ 12.5.0
4. HotChocolate.Types.Scalars @ 12.5.0

I have a query like beloew

```cs
    public IQueryable<EmploymentContract> GetEmploymentContracts([Service] ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
        => dbContext.EmploymentContracts
            .Include(x => x.Person)
            .Include(x => x.Organisation)
            .Include(x => x.Department);
```

and then a descriptor for it like

```cs
        descriptor.Field(x => x.GetEmploymentContracts(_dbContext))
            .UsePaging(options: new PagingOptions { DefaultPageSize = PAGE_SIZE, IncludeTotalCount = true })
            .UseFiltering()
            .UseSorting();
```

Now the issue is that if I run a query like below, it takes even sometimes more than 30 seconds to give back the results. I checked the `ef core` generated `sql query` and that runs in mssql in `200ms`. Whatever is slowing down the request, is happening after ef core runs the query and gets the result from the database.

```
{
    employmentContracts {
        nodes {
            personnelNumber
        }
    }
}
```

As you see, the above query is really simple.

When I remove the `UsePaging` it works fine and I get the results immediately.

But if not, it either will give a `timeout` or will run for 22s or so...

### Edit

The problem is solved and the issue was not with GraphQL.
The model had some images stored in places where the query was happening. The model is changed and the issue is not happening anymore.

Comment: It sounds like your data is pulled in memory and sliced there. Can you create a small repro and create a github issue.

Comment: On the ef core sql query, it is creating the query with ` take (@variable) ` statement.
I will create a repo

Comment: Probably you have a lot of records. Try measure `GetEmploymentContracts(ctx).Count()`

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv, I only have two records. That is why it is strange to me. I'm creating a repo. The model is a bit complicated though. But will see if it will also happen in the simplified version, if not I may be able to compare them and see what is different.

Comment: @MichaelIngmarStaib, I did a simpler project and saw the problem it is not an issue with HotChocolate. The problem is that the Person in EmploymentContract has a navigation to an Image entity. I removed this navigation apparetnly HotChocolate was traversing in it.
Either this was the issue or that image was being stored on the contract because the contract stores a json copy of the time the person has received the contract. But now it is perfect. Thanks :)